Spring Boot Security - configuring using application.yml
I am writing a Spring Boot web application and I would like to make the security aspect configurable using an external file, rather than using Java code.
Unfortunately, I am finding a lot of conflicting information, some of which may be out-of-date.
One approach I have seen is to use an xml file, something like:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
 
<http pattern="/home" security="none"/>
<http use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <http-basic />
</http>
 
 
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
      <user name="userId" password="passwd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
 
</beans:beans>

and then use the ImportResource annotation, like this:
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
public class SpringBootXmlApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootXmlApplication.class, args);
    }
}

However, I was wondering if the same thing could be achieved using the application.yml file?
Thanks,
Carl
